# is there a way to block certain emails from passing orders through the paypal plugin in woocommerce from paypal's end?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

Using paypal plugin to process payment in my woocommerce website. When I ban certain customers only on woorcommerce they are able to enter fake information and pass orders with the same paypal account. Is there anyway to block/ban these users from paypal's side in a way that even if they insert fake information the payment is not processed since they are using the same paypal account.

I tried banning them on woocommerce only but they can reach the paypal button with fake emails.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, yes, though I don't personally know of a prebuilt UI or plugin for it.

When using the latest [woocommerce-paypal-payments](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/) plugin, before the capture step or immediately after the payer's web approval at PayPal the code could do a [get call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get) to get the current PayPal order's details, and if the payer's PayPal email address (or better yet PayPal account ID, since the PayPal email can be changed) is blacklisted, reject capturing it and display some message or (intentionally vague) error. A PHP web developer can make this change, perhaps even using hooks rather than editing the plugin's code directly so that the change will remain in effect when the woocommerce-paypal-payments plugin is updated to a newer version in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in your Paypal account. See in the [documentation](https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/how-do-i-block-another-paypal-user-help614).

It should work with both, personal and business accounts, didn't test it though.